# update to the latest ionic version

Tags: ionic-framework

after ionic team has officially released ionic 1.2 versions
I checked

> ionic -v

command to get my current version and I found it 1.7.12, then I did

> npm install -g ionic

hopefully to update my current version and it just still on the previous version 1.7.12, so what is just the command I have to run to get the ionic 1.2 instead of ionic 1 which I already have now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug in npm, the 1.7.12 version that is shown when you run:

```
ionic -v
1.7.12
```

is the **ionic-cli version, the command line utility**, you can find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic

The ionic 1.2 version that you are expecting, is the **ionic framework version**: http://code.ionicframework.com/# latest is 1.2.4 - Copenhagen

If you want to check the framework version that **your app** is running, go to your app directory and type:

```
ionic lib
Local Ionic version: 1.2.4  (<path>/myApp/www/lib/ionic/version.json)
Latest Ionic version: 1.2.4  (released 2016-01-08)
 * Local version up to date
```

Answer (score 3):

It may be bug with npm.

First Uninstall  ionic and cordova using

```
npm uninstall cordova ionic
```

Then update `node` and `npm`

Install  cordova and ionic

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Check the version.

Answer (score 0):

you can always run

*`sudo npm uninstall -g ionic && sudo npm install ionic`*